# Is there a Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to implement a delegate?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the following scenario, `List<Point>` has a method called `Sort` that accepts a delegate as the parameter. For years, I've always had to lookup (either on MSDN, or meta files) what the delegate (in this case, [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)) takes as parameters and what it returns (if anything).

[image]

I find it strange, since when you're working with `event`, you can usually type `+=`<kbd>Tab</kbd> and it generates a stub of the code for you. But for delegates, that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a Visual Studio shortcut to turn:

`pnts.Sort(`

into

`pnts.Sort(delegate(Point a, Point b) { throw new NotImplementedException(); });`

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing Code Rush or ReSharper add.

Comment: Can you use ReShaper?

Answer (score 2):

ReShaper offers it in IntelliSense.

[image]